# ORM Equivalent for a Star/Snowflake Schema

Tags: database-design, architecture, orm

An ORM (.netTiers, EntityFramework, nHibernate, etc.) can generally be described as bridging the gap between the relational data model and the object oriented model.

Is there an ORM equivalent in the data warehousing world?

The technology would bridge the gap between a denormalized star/snowflake schema and the object oriented model. The goal is to be able to rapidly develop a data layer that sits on top of and consumes said schema.

We are using .Net with MSSQL.

Happy Friday!

Comment: I can't imagine a business case where you have an object oriented model on top of a star schema.  Since MSSQL is a relational database, you can still use a traditional ORM even if the schema isn't strictly relational (but you may lose features like relationship traversal since foreign keys are used differently).  You appear to be in somewhat of a "garbage in, garbage out" situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you practice CQRS (Command/Query Responsibility Separation), you could potentially consider your Data Warehouse the Read Model you are querying against.  Your normalized OLTP database would be the data model your Commands execute against.

That being said, I don't know any any ORM that can speak MDX and talk to a Data Warehouse.

Comment: Marking this as answer -- the original question might not be valid.